# SQL, calculation with SUM to count the current online agents

Tags: sql-server

I try to create a query that gives out the total current amount of online agents (callcenter) and the total current agents ready to receive a call, but my outcome is not how I imagined it to be.

```
select time_stamp, logOn, logOff, ready, notReady 
from availability
order by time_stamp asc
```

This query gives an output of 1 on each "action", for example when someone will sign in, it gives a 1 for logOn at the time_stamp 08:24:58 and a 0 for the other options. It gives an output on each action, therefor 0's are common, as a change in ready/not ready is not a change in logon/logoff.

I have tried many different SUM() functions, but none really give the output I desire. I tried the following (and a few other routes, but I can't find those anymore):

```
 sum(logon-logoff) as 'current online'
 sum(logon)-sum(logoff) as 'current online'
 logon-logoff as 'current online'
 sum(Ready)-sum(not_ready) as 'current ready'
```

The output of these are more a sum of that row than a sum of all total outcomes so far. As I order by time_stamp, there are quite a few rows, but it doesn't adds up as if you would calculate it by hand. I made a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kE0LbgLam1fJDawPjLQ9ZhSflypAIsPehL4se2b-Tbk/edit?usp=sharing) of my outcomes and how I picture the outcome of the SUM() to look like.

I've been stuck here for quite a while, maybe someone knows a solution to my problem. Or maybe what I think I'm looking for isn't what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can give more data, as it is from the company I work at. Have you looked at the spreadsheet?

Comment: 1) Sample data is not expected to be real data, just data that presents the problem - you should ever use real data. 2) No one is going to look at a spreadsheet, pop enough data as formatted text into the question. Frequently when building a sample [mre] people solve their own problems.

Comment: Will try that next time, as someone has found a good solution for me. I thought it would've been easier to show in a spreadsheet as I'm not used to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for running sum:

```
SUM(logon-logoff) OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'current online'
```